# Trying to run Raspberry Pi camera via SSH in remote Windows desktop

Tags: python, linux, windows, image-processing, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to edit my raspberry program files from network via SSH. For trial and error, I had to look at how the camera is going (seeing video lives, editing the picture quality, maybe adding image recognition in the future). The program can't run from the SSH, at least the part that requires "camera view" to open usually in Linux desktop.

Is there any way to do this correctly? I know Raspberry Pi camera library ran on SystemX, as so the GUI library Tkinter, maybe there's a way to cross this somehow to .NET windows GUI?

edit 1: I use Raspbian OS 32 bit for the OS. I use picamera library. If it helps, there's an error says "PiCameraMMALError...:failed to create MMAL component..:out of memory." I tried connecting to SSH via Windows Powershell and Linux subsystem, both gave me same errors.

edit 2: adding error image, might be useful.
[image: The error stays even after enabling the camera and restarting the Pi]

I wonder if there's some mechanism which requires Pi to be connected to monitor to display the camera directly? Or maybe data bandwidth problem? Or just SystemX incompability on ssh hosts?

edit[3]: Adding code snippets to make error checking easier. The code is mostly still just activating camera functions

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from picamera import PiCamera
    from time import sleep
    
    #camera initiation
    camera = PiCamera()
    camera.rotation = 180
    camera.resolution = (1080, 1080)
    
    #camera start
    def cameraStart():
          camera.start_preview()
          camera.preview_fullscreen = False
          camera.preview_window = (0, 0, 650, 480)
    
    #camera stop
    def cameraStop():
         camera.stop_preview()
    
    #main function:
    def main(): 
         while True:
                 cameraStart()
                 print("Menu\n")
                 print(1. Turn off camera")
                 choice = input("Enter the menu:")
                 if choice == 1: 
                       cameraStop()
                       exit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
          main()
```

edit 4: The camera now can works fine without monitor, looks like I misplaced the port before. Thanks to @marksetchell. Now the only problem is to output the camera to windows that ran the ssh. Can it sends the output through my Windows laptop?

Comment: Please be clearer about whether you are using Raspbian or **bullseye**, and 32/64-bit. Please be clearer about whether you are using `raspistill/raspivid` or **libcamera** utilities. Please be clearer as to whether you are connecting via `ssh` from Linux or Windows. Thank you.

Comment: Hi thank you for reaching me out. I use Raspbian OS 32 bit for the OS. I use picamera library. If it helps, there's an error says "PiCameraMMALError...:failed to create MMAL component..:out of memory." I tried connecting to SSH via Windows Powershell and Linux subsystem, both gave me same errors

Comment: The error messages inficates you need to run `sudo raspi-config` and go into the *"Interfacing Options"* and enable the camera and reboot.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did restart and activate the camera but still won't work

Comment: @richardec added, mostly just activating the camera library and it works on the raspberry pi linux GUI OS

Comment: Can you click [edit] and clarify in your question what actually does work please? If you attach a screen and keyboard directly to the Raspberry Pi, can you login and take a still photo with `raspistill`? If that works, can you run your program that uses`picamera` and show exactly what you run and how you run it and exactly what happens please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hi marksetchell thanks for reaching out back. As the edit 4 says, The camera is now working properly, looks like I misplaced the port before. Now I only need projecting it through my  Windows client. Do I need some listener and server on HTTP for that? Or is there any other way so my camera can be projected and ran in my Windows client?

Comment: @Dean Dean. There is new version picamera 2 and new libcamera

Comment: Missing quote. print(1. Turn off camera") to print("1. Turn off camera"). Also I preesed 1 but doesn't stop.

Comment: @toyotaSupra hey, thanks for letting me know. It's maybe it's a typo in code copying process because it does stop when I ran it from mine. What's the difference between picamera2 and new libcamera? Also, is it possible if I ran the camera code from ssh and the raspberry stream the image (video is even better) output to the mentioned ssh laptop?

Comment: picamera is no longer. New Bullseye. Picamera 2 is improvement and new libcamera. You can do anything you want.

Comment: Your laptop comes with built-in camera. I am using resolution 4k monitor. You must have webcam with 4k. Bullseye only. The newest version will be 2023